# Convergence of two improper integrals.

Tags: calculus

I have two integrals:

1. $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{\log(\sin x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x$
2. $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{\log(\sin x)}{\sqrt{x}} \, \mathrm{d}x$

Do they converge? I tried to settle by comparison, but nothing seems to work for me, hence I ask for your help.

Comment: Where is the problematic behaviour of the two integrands?

Comment: in $x=0$, bot that doesn't tell me much

Comment: Knowing that allows you to analyse the problematic behaviour to see whether the improper integrals converge or not. The behaviour of the denominator is obvious. How does the numerator behave near $0$?

Comment: $\log{\sin{x}}$ approaches $- \infty$ as $x$ approaches $0$ from the right. So the whole function approaches $- \infty $ .

Comment: Yes. The question is _how fast?_

Comment: Are you suggesting asymptotic comparison criteria?

Comment: Yes, that's the natural thing to do.

Comment: I don't know. I can't come up with function to compare with...

Comment: Oh, if i compare with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} \sin{x}}$ then I get $  \lim_{x \to 0} \ln{(\sin{x})} \cdot \sin{x} = 0 $

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\,\sin x}$ isn't good. Let's first look at the first. What's your guess, does $\int_0^1 \frac{\log (\sin x)}{x}\,dx$ converge or not?

Comment: I don't really know. If I were to guess, I'd say it does not converge.

Comment: Good. So let's try showing it. Have you any idea for a non-integrable function $f$ such that $f(x) \leqslant \frac{\lvert \log (\sin x)\rvert}{x}$ on $(0,\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$?

Comment: 1. I take $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log{\sin{x}}}{x} \cdot x \sin{x} = 0 $, so now I have to prove, that $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x \cdot \sin{x}}$ diverges.
$\frac{1}{x \cdot \sin{x}} \ge \frac{1}{x}$ for $x \in (0,1]$ , so since $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x}$ diverges I know, that $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x \cdot \sin{x}}$ also diverges by simple comparison, hence using asymptotic criteria my integral diverges. Am I right?

Comment: Answering to your question, like ... $\frac{1}{x}$? Yeah, it makes sense. What about the second one? I can't compare with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ because $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ converges, so it gives me nothing.

Comment: Right, $\frac{1}{x}$ settles the first. For the second, you can take $\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$ with $\frac{1}{2} < \alpha < 1$. Then $x^{\alpha - \frac{1}{2}}\cdot \log (\sin x) \to 0$, and you're home.

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to prove that $\log\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)$ is bounded between $-\frac{x^2}{5}$ and $-\frac{x^2}{6}$ over $(0,1)$, you just have to study the behaviour of:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{x}\,dx,\qquad \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx. $$
The first integral is obviously diverging, since the primitive of $\frac{\log x}{x}$ is $\frac{\log(x)^2}{2}$, while the second integral evaluates to $-4$. The integral 
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x^{\alpha}}\cdot\log\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right) $$
is between $-\frac{1}{5(3-\alpha)}$ and $-\frac{1}{6(3-\alpha)}$ for any $\alpha\in(0,3)$.

---

By using the Weierstrass product for the sine function, we also have:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x}\cdot\log\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\,dx = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{n^2\pi^2}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\zeta(2)}{\pi^2}+\frac{\zeta(4)}{4\pi^4}+\frac{\zeta(6)}{9\pi^6}+\ldots\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint, first note that if $y\to 0^+$, we know by LHR that 
$$\log(y)=O((\frac1y)^\epsilon),\quad\forall \epsilon>0$$
And that
$$\log(1+y)=y+O(y)$$
Then plugging in 
$$\sin x=x+O(x^3)$$
as $x\to 0^+$, we get
$$\log(\sin x)=\log(x+O(x^3))=\log x+\log(1+O(x^2))=O((\frac1x)^\epsilon)+O(x^2)=O((\frac1x)^\epsilon)$$
Which means, near $x=0$, the two integrands belong under the classes 
$$O(x^{1-\epsilon})\quad\text{and}\quad O(x^{\frac12-\epsilon})$$
respectively.

Now recall what you learned about $p-$ integral.